# Is it possible for a car's AC system not to have a dryer in the circuit?

Tags: ac, subaru, repair

I recently fixed a leak in my car's AC system and, prior to evacuating it in order to recharge it with fresh refrigerant, I looked to replace the dryer as recommended. I could not locate a dryer in my car's AC circuit after tracing everything starting from the compressor and back.

I have a 2013 Subaru Impreza (non-turbo). I was also able to get a copy of this model's factory service manual. Nowhere in the manual is a mention of a dryer in the AC system.

My question is, is it really possible to have an AC system without a dryer? Does a complete evacuation obviate the need for one on the assumption that you've removed all the moisture in the system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can but it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

The receiver dryer acts as a filter for any compressor swarf or oil sludge too, not only as a dryer. It's likely inside the condenser. Any AC system has a dryer, especially if there's a TXV. Moisture turns to ice inside the TXV mobile orifice due to flash expansion of the liquid refrigerant, and immediately clogs it up. Look more carefully.